# Nested LINQ queries to filter objects by its sub objects properties

Tags: c#, linq

I am quite new in Linq and I would much appreciace if any oy you can give some help.
I have a collection of nodes that they have a collection of paths. Each path, have a property that represent an string and an a number.

[image]

Tha I need is to get all nodes that contains any path with its path string matches a given string and order the resulting collection by the number value of the matching path.

I would prefer to use linq C# sintax (x => x.xxxx)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: By "matches a given string" do you mean "is exactly the same as a given string"?

Comment: Can you show us the code you currently have? How do the data-structures you like to query currently look like?

Comment: Filtered node may contains many matched paths, which one would to be sort item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a pair of the original Node and the Path matching the string, so you can order the results and get back the node afterwards

```
Nodes
   .Select(n => new { Node = n, Path = n.Paths.FirstOrDefault(p => p.item1 == s) })
   .Where(x => x.Path != null)
   .OrderBy(x => x.Path.item2)
   .Select(x => x.Node)
```

I assume that the Path-strings are unique here. If you need the lowest/highest item2 of all matching paths, I would think about not using LINQ as the expression becomes very complicated